# Automatically generating UI initializations in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

There was an Android Studio plugin that enabled the user to right click and generate XML UI initializations automatically , I cannot find it now and I cannot find any replacement for it , is theres an alternative to writing the initializations of buttons and textviews by hand in Android Studio?

The old plugin used to work by right clicking then selecting "Generate" it work in the same way that getters and setters now work in Android Studio .

Answer (score 0):

if you dont like all the glue code just use [Android Databinding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) or some annotation library like [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) both are great to keep clean the code

Answer (score 0):

I think yo're talking about `ButterKnife Zelezny` plugin.

Check it: https://github.com/avast/android-butterknife-zelezny

Hope it will help